# Change the destination href of an img element by copying the img element src and changing it in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

**Current HTML**

```
<div id="testContainer">
 <a href="testPage.htm" target="_top">
    <img src="/res/images/testImage_M.jpg?lc=en-GB&lv=5.jpg" alt="Test" width="153" height="188" class="linkImage" />
 </a>
</div>
```

I want to be able to use the img src, change part of it (M.jpg with XXL.jpg) and replace the parent href with the image source.

**Desired end result**

```
<div id="testContainer">
     <a href="/res/images/testImage_XXL.jpg?lc=en-GB&lv=5.jpg" target="_top">
        <img src="/res/images/testImage_M.jpg?lc=en-GB&lv=5.jpg" alt="Test" width="153" height="188" class="linkImage" />
     </a>
    </div>
```

I know the .attr() and .removeAttr() but I'm clueless how to change only part of the original img src.

Comment: look up String.replace - e.g. `.attr('src').replace('M.jpg','XXL.jpg')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".linkImage").each(function() {
    this.parentNode.href = this.src.replace("_M.jpg", "_XXL.jpg")
});
```

This finds all the `.linkImage` objects and for each one gets the `img.src` value, changes `_M.jpg` to `_XXL.jpg` in it and assigns that to the parent link as it's `href`.

---

While the above works fine for the exact HTML you have, you can make it a little more robust against future tweaks to the HTML, by doing this:

```
$(".linkImage").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("a").attr("href", this.src.replace("_M.jpg", "_XXL.jpg"));
});
```

This finds the first ancestor that is an `<a>` tag rather than assuming that the `<a>` tag is always the direct parent of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
$('a').each(function () {
   var src = $('.linkImage', this).attr('src');
   if (src) {
      $(this).attr('href', src.replace('_M.jpg', '_XXL.jpg'));
   }
});
```

This probably matches more elements than you need. Adjust the selectors according to your situation.

Comment: why use regex replace, when simple string replace would work, e.g. `src.replace("M.jpg", "XXL.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var imgsrc=$('a').find('img').attr('src');
var newsrc=imgsrc.replace("M.jpg","XXL.jpg");

$('a').attr("href",newsrc).find('img').attr('src',newsrc);
```

Comment: This only works if there is only one `<a>` tag in the whole document.  If there are multiple `<a>` tags, it gives them all the same href.  It also changes the img `.src` which isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: u can always be specific with your selectors providing id and class..I just provided him with the code flow

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code for changing url of hyperlink :

```
var src = $('img').attr('src').replace('M.jpg', 'XXL.jpg'); 
$('a').attr('href',src);
```

Show this Link Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/4/